# Swift - Parsing Data Error - Swift.DecodingError.dataCorrupted

Tags: json, swift, parsing

I'm using SwiftSoup in combination with Codable to get the correct element(s) and parse the data. However, I receive this error:

```
JSON decode failed: Swift.DecodingError.dataCorrupted(Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "The given data was not valid JSON.", underlyingError: Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "No value." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=No value.})))
```

I've looked online, ensure my data matches correctly, even change the expected types from Int to String but got an error stating an Int was expected.

This is the data I am receiving and can print in the console:

```
data - 
{"test":0,"ppace":85,"pshooting":92,"ppassing":91,"pdribbling":95,"pdefending":38,"pphysical":65,"acceleration":91,"sprintspeed":80,"agility":91,"balance":95,"reactions":94,"ballcontrol":96,"dribbling":96,"positioning":93,"finishing":95,"shotpower":86,"longshotsaccuracy":94,"volleys":88,"penalties":75,"interceptions":40,"headingaccuracy":70,"marking":32,"standingtackle":35,"slidingtackle":24,"vision":95,"crossing":85,"freekickaccuracy":94,"shortpassing":91,"longpassing":91,"curve":93,"jumping":68,"stamina":72,"strength":69,"aggression":44,"composure":96}
```

This is my function:

```
 func parseData() {
    do {
    let html = try String(contentsOf: url!, encoding: String.Encoding.ascii)
        let doc: Document = try! SwiftSoup.parse(html)
        let elements = try doc.getAllElements()
        for element in elements {
            switch element.id() {
            case "player_stats_json":
              
                let content = try! element.getElementsContainingText("ppace").text()
                print(content.utf8)
                let jsonData = content.data(using: .utf8)
                    do {
                        self.player = try JSONDecoder().decode(PlayerModel.self, from: Data(jsonData!))
                    } catch let jsonError as NSError {
                        print("JSON decode failed: \(jsonError)")
                        print("data - \(content)")
                    }
            default:
                break
            }
        }

    } catch Exception.Error(type: let type, Message: let message) {
        print(type)
        print(message)
    } catch {
        print("")
    }
    }
```

And this is my model file:

```
struct PlayerModel: Codable {
    var test: Int
    var ppace: Int
    var pshooting: Int
    var ppassing: Int
    var pdribbling: Int
    var pdefending: Int
    var pphysical: Int
    var acceleration: Int
    var sprintspeed: Int
    var agility: Int
    var balance: Int
    var reactions: Int
    var ballcontrol: Int
    var dribbling: Int
    var positioning: Int
    var finishing: Int
    var shotpower: Int
    var longshotsaccuracy: Int
    var volleys: Int
    var penalties: Int
    var interceptions: Int
    var headingaccuracy: Int
    var marking: Int
    var standingtackle: Int
    var slidingtackle: Int
    var vision: Int
    var crossing: Int
    var freekickaccuracy: Int
    var shortpassing: Int
    var longpassing: Int
    var curve: Int
    var jumping: Int
    var stamina: Int
    var strength: Int
    var aggression: Int
    var composure: Int
}
```

I've double and tripled checked the variable names match up with each key. I've pasted the outputted data in the console in an Online JSON validator, and no errors appear. I'm genuinley left scratching my head right now, because I can't understand where I've gone wrong.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222809/discussion-on-question-by-swiftuser-swift-parsing-data-error-swift-decodinge).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I still have no idea whats wrong with your parsing. I've managed to parse your html but I have no idea why when trying to use Int instead of Uint8 it kept failing to return the right values. This is what worked for me:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
struct PlayerModel: Codable {
    let test: UInt8
    let ppace: UInt8
    let pshooting: UInt8
    let ppassing: UInt8
    let pdribbling: UInt8
    let pdefending: UInt8
    let pphysical: UInt8
    let acceleration: UInt8
    let sprintspeed: UInt8
    let agility: UInt8
    let balance: UInt8
    let reactions: UInt8
    let ballcontrol: UInt8
    let dribbling: UInt8
    let positioning: UInt8
    let finishing: UInt8
    let shotpower: UInt8
    let longshotsaccuracy: UInt8
    let volleys: UInt8
    let penalties: UInt8
    let interceptions: UInt8
    let headingaccuracy: UInt8
    let marking: UInt8
    let standingtackle: UInt8
    let slidingtackle: UInt8
    let vision: UInt8
    let crossing: UInt8
    let freekickaccuracy: UInt8
    let shortpassing: UInt8
    let longpassing: UInt8
    let curve: UInt8
    let jumping: UInt8
    let stamina: UInt8
    let strength: UInt8
    let aggression: UInt8
    let composure: UInt8
}
```

---

```
let url = URL(string:"https://www.futbin.com/21/player/541/lionel-messi")!
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
    guard let data = data, let html = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) else { return }
    if let start = html.range(of: #"<div style="display: none;" id="player_stats_json">"#)?.upperBound,
       let end = html[start...].range(of: #"</div>"#)?.lowerBound {
        let json = html[start..<end]
        do {
            let player = try JSONDecoder().decode(PlayerModel.self, from: Data(json.utf8))
            print(player)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}.resume()
```

---

This will print

> PlayerModel(test: 0, ppace: 85, pshooting: 92, ppassing: 91,
> pdribbling: 95, pdefending: 38, pphysical: 65, acceleration: 91,
> sprintspeed: 80, agility: 91, balance: 95, reactions: 94, ballcontrol:
> 96, dribbling: 96, positioning: 93, finishing: 95, shotpower: 86,
> longshotsaccuracy: 94, volleys: 88, penalties: 75, interceptions: 40,
> headingaccuracy: 70, marking: 32, standingtackle: 35, slidingtackle:
> 24, vision: 95, crossing: 85, freekickaccuracy: 94, shortpassing: 91,
> longpassing: 91, curve: 93, jumping: 68, stamina: 72, strength: 69,
> aggression: 44, composure: 96)

Comment: I've just copied in your function and now I've seemed to have success with it. Even appended to an array on PlayerModels whilst keeping all values as Ints within my Model class.

Comment: @SwiftUser Glad to help. I think you should find an API to return a JSON instead of parsing it from an html if possible.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and effort! I honestly appreciate it. There is an API that's available to pay for, which I don't mind. I tried contacting them in the hopes of a deal. However, their email wasn't send. One question, I see you used html.range start and end to point in the right direction of the data which should be parsed, is it possible to create multiple ranges? And parse the data all at once?

Comment: And I honestly think, the issue was using SwiftSoup.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32305891/index-of-a-substring-in-a-string-with-swift/32306142#32306142 this will return ranges but you have different strings to find.

Comment: You would need to use NSRegularExpression and get the group ranges. This might help if you know how to create regex patterns https://stackoverflow.com/a/64235708/2303865

Comment: I see, I'll look into that as I need to get more data such as ` <img alt="n" id="player_nation"` etc. Once again, I am grateful for your help.