# Why is it necessary to refer to self for the Identifiable protocol?

Tags: swift, protocols, associated-types

In apple's implementation of Identifiable

the required function is

```
associatedtype ID
var id: Self.ID { get }
```

why is self required? What is the difference between that and

```
associatedtype ID
var id: ID { get }
```

Comment: `Self` represents the type that conforms to the protocol.

Comment: yes I understand that, but why is it there? The second code already does that

Comment: It is not required. You can omit it most of the time.

Comment: They probably have added to be able to refer to it in their documentation. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64286377/swift-parsing-data-error-swift-decodingerror-datacorrupted?noredirect=1#64287150

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is just a convention Apple uses when writing their documentation. They write all their associated types with the `Self.` prefix. Examples: [1](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/strideable/1641148-advanced), [2](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/toplevelencoder/encode(_:)), [3](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/expressiblebyintegerliteral/2298913-init). This is so that it is clear what is an associated type, and what isn't. If the declaration for `Identifiable.id` has instead been written like:

```
var id: ID { get }
```

To someone who's never used SwiftUI before, it is unclear whether `ID` is an entirely separate, top-level type, or an associated type. If it said `Self.ID`, however, it is clear that `ID` is an associated type of a protocol.

Other than that, the `Self.` prefix does not mean anything special. It's just like the `self.` prefix when referring to a instance member. It is optional in most cases. Just like the `self.` prefix, you probably *need* `Self.` to resolve name conflicts in some situations, though I can't think of any right now.

Apple also seems to have a convention for nested types - to always write out `OuterTypeName.InnerTypeName`, when just `InnerTypeName` is enough. [Example](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsondecoder/2949119-keydecodingstrategy):

```
var keyDecodingStrategy: JSONDecoder.KeyDecodingStrategy
```

Comment: But does it function exactly the same?

Comment: @erotsppa yes. See the third paragraph.